# If I do not do any data normailization, is datagen.fit required in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I use keras for training an image classification problem as follows:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(x_train)


# alternative to model.fit_generator
for e in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', e)
    batches = 0
    for x_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32):
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
        batches += 1
        if batches >= len(x_train) / 32:
            # we need to break the loop by hand because
            # the generator loops indefinitely
            break
```

I would like to know if `datagen.fit` is required if I do not apply any data normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment of the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) in the code:

```
# compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
# (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied)
datagen.fit(x_train)
```

It does the normalization, reducing mean and dividing by standard deviation, and more things like `PCA`. So it seems that you don't need to do normalization. That method does that, and normalizing features is required for accelerating training process and caring about all features with different scales the same.

Comment: one more question friend, if I add the following for validation : `ValidScore = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val, batch_size=32,verbose =1)` directly after `model.fit` is applied, would I have to apply `datagen.flow` to my `(x_val, y_val)` ?

Comment: @unknown121 yes, definitely. Your validation data should be normalized as well. Because your network has learned the normalized data, so the validation data should be normalized too.

Comment: i) But if I do not normalize and only apply rotation, is it still necessary to do the `datagen.flow`?        ii)I am passing the valid. data this way but it is not allowing me to : ` TrainScore =model.fit(x_batch,y_batch,callbacks=[lr_reduce,model_checkpoint],verbose =1,validation_data=datagen.flow(x_val, y_val ))`

Comment: @unknown121 data normalization is different from transformation and translation. Are your familiar with that?

Comment: ok yes so `datagen.fit` is not needed when transformations are applied then. Also how can I apply `datagen.flow` to validation data. I am trying this but giving an error of improper arguments: `TrainScore=model.fit(x_batch,y_batch,callbacks=[lr_reduce,model_checkpoint],verbose =1,validation_data=datagen.flow(x_val, y_val ))`

Comment: @unknown121 I didn't get what you mean by *validating*.

Comment: By validation, I mean a hold out sample to test the trained model

Comment: @unknown121 Why don't you just use predict? I've not seen that problem. Maybe it's better to ask it separately.